# Why state of entity returned from JpaRepository in normal thread and async thread are different

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I used to think that any entities returned by a JpaRepository will be in DETACH state because in Spring the default PersistentContextType is TRANSACTION and when we get the returned values at the caller of a JpaRepository, the transaction used to get those entities has been closed.

But recently, I unexpectedly found down that it depend. I have this sample code.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BookService {
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;
    private final UpdateService updateService;
    @PersistenceContext
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public Book updateAuthor(String bookId, String author) {
        Book book = bookRepository.findById(bookId).get();
        entityManager.contains(book); // true
        Book updateBook = updateService.updateAuthorTransactional(book, author);
        return updateBook;
    }

    @Async
    public Book updateAuthorAsync(String bookId, String author) {
        Book book = bookRepository.findById(bookId).get();
        entityManager.contains(book); // false
        Book updatedBook =  updateService.updateAuthorTransactional(book, author);
        return updatedBook;
    }

    public void updateAuthorExecutor(String bookId, String author) {
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).submit(() -> {
            Book book = bookRepository.findById(bookId).get();
            entityManager.contains(book); // false
            Book updateBook = updateService.updateAuthorTransactional(book, author);
            return updateBook;
        });
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UpdateService {

    @Transactional
    public Book updateAuthorTransactional(Book book, String author) {
        book.setAuthor(author);
        return book;
    }
}
```

The BookRepository is a simple empty interface which extends JpaRepositoty. Book is a entity with 3 fields: id, title, author. I use H2 to init 2 records of Book using this

```
insert into `test`.`book` values ( '101', 'Book101', null );
insert into `test`.`book` values ( '102', 'Book102', null );
```

When I trigger method BookService.updateAuthor(), the state of returned entity is PERSISTED. I conclude that because EntityManager.contain() return true and after the method UpdateService.updateAuthorTransactional() is executed, the transaction is closed, the persistent context is flushed and the new value of author is updated to database.

But this isn't the case with other two methods in BookService. The EntityManager.contain() return false and the new value of author is not updated to database.

So I wonder

1. What makes the difference behind the scene here?
2. Which persistent context stores the book entity in updateAuthor() method? What is about its life-cycle like when it is initialized, closed?
3. I used to think that when the transaction close, all entities in the persistent context will be transitioned to DETACH state. Is this still correct? Is there something different with Spring Data Jpa?

Update: Look like the web container has created a persistent context somewhere for the main thread, and all repository method call in main thread will share this same persistent context. In case of async thread, there is no such persistent context for the thread. It will be created and closed by proxied Jpa repository method. This result into what i get. Just my guess from the phenomenon, I can not find any document to prove this.

Comment: Different threads, different entitymanagers. Why because not the whole method is transactional. Also by default there is open entitymanager in view enabled, so if you use a single thread you use a single entitymanager. when multithreaded, in those case, you use at least 2 different ones.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you explain in more details? It's not clear to me. It doesn't explain why changes in normal thread is saved but not async thread.
 A reference link will be good.

Comment: An `EntityManager` is bound to a thread, in the case of async usage you are using multiple threads (which is why `contains` returns `false` because that is bound to **thread 1** and it is being read with **thread 2** so the `EntityManger` of **thread 1** doesn't contain the read entity). As it is detached, there is no change detected and thus nothing to save. Setting something in a transactional method **without** calling save for a detached entity does just that, nothing.

Comment: @M.Deinum In case contain() return true, does it mean that a transaction and a persistent context has been created for this thread from start and in Jpa repository, query is sent to database using the same transaction?

Comment: Using the same `EntityManager` the transaction doesn't make any difference in this case (at least for the async one as the `Book` entity is never reattached )

Comment: This entity manager instance is container-managed. I wonder where its persistent context come from? Is it associated with any transaction?
We saw that in the async thread, the returned entity isn't attached but in the normal it's attached. 

The implementation of Jpa repository has its own Transactional annotation with the default behavior. So if there is no existing transaction when it's called, it will create a new one and returned entity should be detached in both scenario because the transaction used to execute query has been closed.

Comment: Please read... An `EntityManager` is thread-bound, as you are injecting it into your service this is bound to the **main** thread. Now when executing everything not async, that `EntityManager` is shared by all operations and nothing will be detached (which is why `contains` returns `true`). With async you have still the `EntityManager` that is injected bound to the **main** thread but there is another `EntityManager` bound to the async thread. You are checking in the main thread if that contains it it doesn't because those are 2 different instances.

Comment: Detaching has nothing to do with the transaction but the span of the `Entitymanager`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237585/discussion-between-huy-ha-and-m-deinum).